# SQLite Database does not update data

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I'm trying to insert some Data using AsyncTask in background. My logcat is telling me that everything is going well and data is inserted. But when i look inside the table.db there is no data inside. I'm using a emulator to see the table.db.

Here is my AsyncTask class:

```
public class ReadRssBackground extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void> {
    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    Context ctx;
    String id, title, link, category;

    public ReadRssBackground(Context context) {
        ctx = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Context... contexts) {
        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
        checkXML(GetData());
        return null;
    }
public void checkXML(Document data) {
    if (data != null) {
        Element root = data.getDocumentElement();
        Node channel = root.getChildNodes().item(1);
        NodeList items = channel.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentChild = items.item(i);

            if (currentChild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item") && count < 5) {
                count++;
                NodeList itemChilds = currentChild.getChildNodes();

                for (int j = 0; j < itemChilds.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node current = itemChilds.item(j);

                    if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        title = current.getTextContent();
                        Log.d("Vergleich Title", current.getTextContent());
                    } else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                        link = current.getTextContent();
                        Log.d("Vergleich Link", current.getTextContent());
                    } else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("category")) {
                        category = current.getTextContent();
                        Log.d("Vergleich Category", current.getTextContent());
                    }
                }
     myDB.insertData(String.valueOf(count),title,link,category);
            }
        }
    }
}

public Document GetData() {
    try {
        url = new URL(adress);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(inputStream);
        return xmlDoc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

And here my DatabaseHelper:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final Context myContext;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "title.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "feed_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "TITLE";
public static final String COL_3 = "LINK";
public static final String COL_4 = "CATEGORY";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,TITLE TEXT,LINK TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}


public boolean insertData(String id, String title, String link, String category) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
    contentValues.put(COL_2, title);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, link);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, category);
    Log.d("Vergleich insert check:", contentValues.toString());
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result == (-1)) {
        Log.d("Vergleich insert:", "DATA INSERTED");
        return false;
    } else {
        Log.d("Vergleich insert:", "NOT");
        return true;
    }
}
```

And the logcat:

```
> 08-25 04:48:00.102 3244-3309/? D/Vergleich Title: Anhörung in
> Neuseeland: Kim Dotcom wehrt sich gegen Auslieferung 08-25
> 04:48:00.102 3244-3309/? D/Vergleich Link:
> http://www.spiegel.de/netzwelt/web/anhoerung-in-neuseeland-dotcom-wehrt-sich-gegen-auslieferung-a-1109396.html#ref=rss
> 08-25 04:48:00.102 3244-3309/? D/Vergleich Category: Netzwelt 08-25
> 04:48:00.102 3244-3309/? D/Vergleich insert check:: ID=1
> CATEGORY=Netzwelt
> LINK=http://www.spiegel.de/netzwelt/web/anhoerung-in-neuseeland-dotcom-wehrt-sich-gegen-auslieferung-a-1109396.html#ref=rss
> TITLE=Anhörung in Neuseeland: Kim Dotcom wehrt sich gegen Auslieferung
> 08-25 04:48:00.102 3244-3309/? D/Vergleich insert:: DATA INSERTED
> 08-25 04:48:00.102 3244-3309/? D/Vergleich Title: Paisley Park:
> Studios von Prince bald offen für Besucher  08-25 04:48:00.102
> 3244-3309/? D/Vergleich Link:
> http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/musik/paisley-park-studios-von-prince-bald-offen-fuer-besucher-a-1109401.html#ref=rss
> 08-25 04:48:00.102 3244-3309/? D/Vergleich Category: Kultur 08-25
> 04:48:00.102 3244-3309/? D/Vergleich insert check:: ID=2
> CATEGORY=Kultur
> LINK=http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/musik/paisley-park-studios-von-prince-bald-offen-fuer-besucher-a-1109401.html#ref=rss
> TITLE=Paisley Park: Studios von Prince bald offen für Besucher  08-25
> 04:48:00.102 3244-3309/? D/Vergleich insert:: DATA INSERTED
```

When i get the feedback, that my data is inserted, why is nothing inside the table? What am i doing wrong?

Here is my BackgroundService where i call ReadRssBackground:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
    private boolean isRunning;
    private Context context;
    private Thread backgroundThread;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.context=this;
        this.isRunning=false;
        this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
        super.onCreate();
    }

    private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do something in Background
            ReadRssBackground readRss = new ReadRssBackground(context);
            readRss.execute();

            stopSelf();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.isRunning=false;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(!this.isRunning){
            this.isRunning=true;
            this.backgroundThread.start();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: title.db or table.db?

Comment: on `db.insert()` if you get -1, an error occured, like stated in the API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29 . You switched the statements, in reality you get an error

Comment: You are displaying the message `Vergleich insert:: DATA INSERTED` when the results of the `db.insert` operation is `-1` - which means you see this message because the data was not inserted.  Are you getting any errors when you examine your log cat?

Comment: Ohhhhhh. My fault. Thank you very much. But can anyone tell me why i get an error?

Comment: @Opoo -> the name of the table is title.db of course.

Answer (score 1):

In your routine checkXML(GetData()); you are not using the parameter data

```
public void checkXML(Document data) {

              myDB.insertData(id,title,link,category);

            }
```

In your constructor you don't have attribute parameters :

```
public ReadRssBackground(Context context) {
    ctx = context.getApplicationContext();
}
```

Replace it with :

```
 public ReadRssBackground(Context context, String id, String title, String link, String category) {
            this.ctx = context;
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.link = link;
            this.category = category;
        }
```

have you already try this :

```
 @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Context... contexts) {
    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    myDB.insertData(id,title,link,category);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. My code above is only a part of my whole code. Dont care about the parameter data. I wish to insert any data in checkXML() like myDB.insertData("id","title","link","category");  I tryied what you said, but i still can not insert any data.

Comment: Yes but you need to call your constructor like this : ReadRssBackground readRssBackground = new ReadRssBackground(context, "id here","title here", "link here", "category here");

Comment: Still the same. I edited my code above and pasted the whole checkXML() with the Document GetData(). Also the background service where i call ReadRssBackground.

Comment: Anyway. Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: Don't give up fast ;). By the way did you call your class ReadRssBackground in your code ? for example : ReadRssBackground readRssBackground = new ReadRssBackground(context, "id here","title here", "link here", "category here"); readRssBackground.execute(context);

Comment: In my BackgroundService i call ReadRssBackground readRss = new ReadRssBackground(context);  I also tried your Version with all parameters.